# pg_restore but previsously clean the destiny DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have an `sh script` that executes a dump from pro and restore test database.

It is something like this:

```
pg_dump 
echo "Users Backup: DONE"

pg_dumpall 
echo "Data Backup: DONE"

sed 's/NOBYPASSRLS//g' users.sql > users_clean.sql
echo "Parse User Backup: DONE"

psql -h host -d db -U user -f users_clean.sql
echo "Restore Users: DONE"

psql -h host -d db -U user -c "
DROP SCHEMA s1 CASCADE;
DROP SCHEMA s2 CASCADE;"
echo "DROP SCHEMAS: DONE"

pg_restore -h host -d db -U user data.sql
echo "RESTORE DATA: DONE"

rm *.sql
echo "DROP BACKUP: DONE"
```

The problem is that drop schema takes too much time.
I thought with the possibility to change this to `dropdb` statement in psql, but as I am trying to drop the database that I want to connect it uses postgres or template1 database.

I do not want to add more users to `.pgpass` because these three databases does not share any user more than root, and I do not want to specify this neither `.pgpass` or `sh script`.

Any other idea, or any other statement to improve performance in raise the dump?

Thanls.

Comment: May be you can only try to use schema only instead of db.

Comment: `DROP SCHEMA ... CASCADE` should be fast. How many tables do you have in a schema? Perhaps you are locked by concurrent transactions; you should terminate those first.

Comment: As a workaround you could rename the schema and drop it later.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have 35 and 165 tables respectively. Probably is the locked concurrent transaction.

Comment: That's *nothing*. Unless something very weird is going on, it hast to be a lock.